# Django updating password does not work

Tags: django, passwords

I created the a page that allows a user to edit their profile information.

Whenever, a user changed a password, it does not update the database and somewhat corrupt the password.

edit_user.html

```
<form style="display:inline"class="form-signin" action="/edit_user/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info"> Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.Form): 
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    firstname = forms.CharField(label='First Name', max_length=15, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    lastname = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', max_length=15, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    #zip = forms.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0),MaxValueValidator(99999)], label="Zipcode", widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    oldPassword = forms.CharField(required=False, label='Current Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    password1 = forms.CharField(required=False, label="New Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(required=False, label="Confirm New Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-control'}))

    def clean_password(self):
        if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
            if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
                raise forms.ValidationError(_("The two password fields did not match."))
        return self.cleaned_data
```

views.py

```
@login_required
def edit_user(request):
    if '_auth_user_id' in request.session:
        u = User.objects.get(id=request.session['_auth_user_id'])

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
            form.fields["email"].initial = u.email
            form.fields["firstname"].initial = u.first_name
            form.fields["lastname"].initial = u.last_name

            if form.is_valid():
                fname = form.cleaned_data['firstname']
                lname = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
                email = form.cleaned_data['email']
                oldPassword = form.cleaned_data['oldPassword']
                pword = form.cleaned_data['password1']

                # if oldPassword != u.password:
                #     #"The current password does not match with your old password!"
                #     return render(request, 'edit_user.html', { 'form': form})

                User.objects.filter(id=u.id).update(first_name = fname, last_name = lname, email = email, password = pword)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/edit_user/')

        else:
            form = UserProfileForm()
            form.fields["email"].initial = u.email
            form.fields["firstname"].initial = u.first_name
            form.fields["lastname"].initial = u.last_name

        variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form})
        return render(request, 'edit_user.html', variables, )
```

When I go in Admin Settings, and check the user's password, it displays this:

```
Password:
Invalid password format or unknown hashing algorithm.

Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this user's password, but you can change the password using this form.
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is django protecting you from accidentally storing a password in plain text.

To set the password for a user, call:

```
user.set_password(new_password)
```

This will store the password in the [correct (hashed) format](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/).

It is worth noting that django already has [a pre-built view for changing passwords](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change).

---

As a side-note, you should be aware that this is not required ...

```
if '_auth_user_id' in request.session:
    u = User.objects.get(id=request.session['_auth_user_id'])
```

... because you can get the user directly off the request:

```
u = request.user
if u.is_authenticated():
    ...
```

Comment: It is still giving the same "Invalid password format or unknown hashing..." after adding `u.set_password(pword)`

Comment: Have you removed `password = pword` from the call to `update`?

Comment: You will also need to call `u.save()` afterwards. I would not recommend that you use the `update` method at all in this view.

Comment: Alright thank you, that works. Mind explaining me why I should not use the update method? Thanks.

Comment: The `update` method is intended for bulk operations, really. It's not exactly wrong to use it for one object, but it does seem a little odd. The problem with it becomes much more obvious when you need to do something like this to a single object: it's not possible to call `update` on the queryset and set the password on one object... Well it *is* possible, but not in one database hit. `:)`